# My backpropagation is producing utter trash

Tags: c++, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm a hobbyist and thus dont have much experience on neural networks, this is my first attempt to implement one.
My backpropagation function is doing something, but not what it is supposed to do.
The network is not getting any better at what I'm training it on (after like 10000 training examples). Implementations from the Internet work on this problem, so it has to be something in this code.

```
void backprop(std::vector<std::vector<neuron>>& neuronen, std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<weight>>>& weights, int rlayer, std::vector<float> target, float learnrate) {
    for (int i = 0; i < weights[rlayer].size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < weights[rlayer][i].size(); j++) {
            weights[rlayer][i][j].changeweight(weights[rlayer][i][j].weightout() +  (learnrate * (target[i] - neuronen[rlayer][i].actout()) * actfAbl(neuronen[rlayer][i].zout()) * neuronen[rlayer - 1][j].actout())); 
        }
    }

    if (rlayer > 1) {
        std::vector<float> newtarget;

        for (int i = 0; i < neuronen[rlayer - 1].size(); i++) {
            float dzdol1 = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < neuronen[rlayer].size(); j++) {
                dzdol1 = weights[rlayer][j][i].weightout() * actfAbl(neuronen[rlayer][j].zout() * (2 * neuronen[rlayer][j].actout() - target[j]));
            }
            std::cout << "dzdol1: " << dzdol1 << std::endl;
            newtarget.push_back(dzdol1);
        }
        backprop(neuronen, weights, rlayer - 1, newtarget, learnrate);
    }
    return;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your first layer is 0 then the condition should be `if(rlayer > 0)`

Comment: Yes, incredible how i didn't see this. Still doesn't work though...

Comment: In my first neural network effort, I 'forgot' to initialize the weights to random values.  Nothing worked.